# python return none instead of True/False

Tags: python, binary-search

I have two programs for searching using binary search in Python

Program 1:

```
def bin(alist,x):
    if len(alist)==0:
        return False
    else:
        mid=len(alist)//2
        if (alist[mid]==x):
            return True 
        else:
            if alist[mid] < x:
                #print(alist[mid+1:],x)
                bin(alist[mid+1:],x)
            else:   
                #print(alist[:mid],x)
                bin(alist[:mid],x)

print (bin([2,3,5,8,9],8))
print (bin([2,3,5,8,9],7))
```

Program output:

```
None
None
```

Program 2:

```
def bin(alist,x):
     if len(alist)==0:
        return False
     else:
        mid=len(alist)//2
        if (alist[mid]==x):
           return  True
        else:
            if alist[mid]<x:
                return bin(alist[mid+1:],x)
            else:
                return bin(alist[:mid],x)
print(bin([1,5,7,8,9],10))
print(bin([1,4,5,8,9],8))
```

Program output:

```
False
True
```

Why is it so?

Comment: I answered the same question a few days ago! Must have been from the same textbook!

Comment: you have `return` in your Program 2

Comment: `return` only returns the value one level up the call stack. If you want to send the value up multiple function calls, each function needs to `return` the value explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program 1, only when the list is empty or the  value you are searching for in the middle of the list, it would returns you boolean value, that's because you explicitly say `return` if `len(alist)==0` and `return True` when it meets `if (alist[mid]==x):`, you have to do the same for the rest conditions as well

```
def bin(alist,x):
    if len(alist)==0:
        return False
    else:
        mid=len(alist)//2
        if (alist[mid]==x):
            return True 
        else:
            if alist[mid] < x:
                #print(alist[mid+1:],x)
                bin(alist[mid+1:],x)   # -------> return 
            else:   
                #print(alist[:mid],x)
                bin(alist[:mid],x)  # -------> return
```

When you invoke your `bin()` method recursively and expect a boolean value, you have to add return in the above highlighted lines.